# How to get current week number in email body (.HTMLBody) using vba

Tags: excel, vba

We are publishing emails in which the body contains current week number. I have the vba code ready for the email (reference rondebruin) but I'm not able to get current week to populate in the email body.

```
Private Sub Send_Email() 
  Dim OutApp As Object 
  Dim OutMail As Object 

  On Error GoTo errorhandler 
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 

  With OutMail 
    .to = "" 
    .CC = "" '' 
    .BCC = "" 
    .Subject = "Reports" 
    .HTMLBody = "Hello All," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Reports for [week_nm] have been published and saved to the designated locations." 
    .Send 
  End With 

  On Error GoTo 0 
  Set OutMail = Nothing 
  Set OutApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: you should provide the relevant code snippet where you stuck

Comment: 'code'
Private Sub Send_Email() 
Dim OutApp As Object 
Dim OutMail As Object 
On Error GoTo errorhandler 
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 
With 
OutMail .to = "" 
.CC = "" ''
.BCC = "" 
.Subject = "Reports" 
.HTMLBody = "Hello All," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Reports for [week_nm] have been published and saved to the designated locations." 
.Send 
End With 
On Error GoTo 0 
Set OutMail = Nothing 
Set OutApp = Nothing 
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current week number of the year, use:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum (Now())
```

In your code, alter the body line to something like..

```
.HTMLBody = "Hello All," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Reports for week " & Application.WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(Now()) & " have been published and saved to the designated locations."
```

Comment: Private Sub Send_Email()

Dim MainWb, LogWb As Workbook
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

On Error GoTo errorhandler

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail

        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        ''.BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Reports"
        .HTMLBody = "Hello All," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Reports for [week_nm] have been published and saved to the designated locations." 
        .Send

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing

    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, I was wondering if there's anyway we can get the Fiscal Week number?

Comment: Just subtract from the `Now()` element the number of days between the 1st of Jan and the 1st day of your fiscal calendar.

Comment: Thanks for your help!